# Include default "Select Option" in MVC Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My Model contains an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and the View contains a `DropDownListFor` that works fine with the exception that I need to include a default "Select an Option" with a value of -1 in some cases.

In the Controller:

```
model.Items = _context.SomeTable.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = m.SomeName,
    Value = m.SomeId
});
```

In the View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    w => Model.ItemId,
    new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text", Model.ItemId),
    new { @class = "form-control text-left" })
```

Between the Controller or View, how can I add the following as the first option and conditionally selected (if ItemId == -1)?

```
<option value="Select an Item">Select an Item</option>
```

Since the logic that determines whether there is an option currently selected is in the Controller I would prefer to add this in the Controller - if possible. Or, if i can get the `<option ...` added in the View and be selected when the Controller passes -1 as ItemId that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a default item you can try

```
model.Items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "Please Select", Value = "-1" });
```

That will push the item to the top of the select list for you. Do this after you have called

```
model.Items = _context.SomeTable.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = m.SomeName,
    Value = m.SomeId
}).ToList();
```

It's important that you add a call to `ToList()` though, so that you are working with a projected list of items, not just the enumerator.

Comment: Even after appending `.ToList()` I don't have an option of `.Insert(...)`

Comment: Ahh, OK. What type is `Items`?

Comment: It's an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Comment: Change it to be `IList<SelectListItem>`. That way, `Insert` will be available to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is an override for 'DropDownListFor' that takes an 'optionLabel' as an argument

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.id, "select one", Model.selectList, new {})
```

You might want to check what value that it generates for that option. I think its either 0 or -1

Comment: Thank you Shoe. I was hoping to do this in the Controller and Jason's answer helped me out.

Comment: The option label argument achieves the same affect just that you know